# $|\bar{F}:F|=\infty$ implies that the degree of the irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ is unbounded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $F$ be a field and $\bar{F}$ be its algebraic closure. Is it true that $|\bar{F}:F|=\infty$ implies that the degree of the irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ is unbounded?

I believe it is, and in this case an hint in the right direction for a proof would be enough, but I don't know where to begin

Comment: Proving the contrapositive seems like it might be easier. I.e. if every minimal polynomial has degree at most $n$, then the degree of the extension to the algebraic closure is finite (probably some function of $n$).

Comment: If $F$ is not perfect, then there are irreducible polynomials of arbitrary large degree over $F$. If $F$ is perfect, then degree of irreducible polynomials bounded implies $|\bar{F}:F|<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Try contrapositive.

Assume that the degree of irreducible polynomials is bounded. Let $N$ be a bound on this.

Then if $a \in \bar{F}$ we have 
$$[F(a):F] \leq N$$

Now, pick some $a$ so that $[F(a):F]$ is maximal.

If $b \in \bar{F}$ try to find some $\alpha \in F, \alpha \neq 0$ so that 
$$a \in F(a+\alpha b)$$

This is always possible if $F$ is infinite.

Comment: If $a\in F(a+\alpha b)$ then $b\in F(a+\alpha b)$, so $F(a,b)=F(a+\alpha b)$. How did you get this? (Usually this works if $b$ is separable, but here isn't the case.)